# Biztalk vs SQL Server Integration Services

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I took a training on BizTalk 2010 and found very help but I got very confused when i started reading about SQL Server Integration Services, so I have following questions;

1. Where to use BizTalk vs SSIS?
2. Does SSIS have VS 2010 project template like we have for BizTalk Server?
3. For SSIS development which IDE should be used, can we use VS 2010 or need to work in SQL Server Management Studio?
4. What are the shortcomings of SSIS that BizTalk overcomes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the fundamental difference is that SSIS is designed to run at scheduled intervals or one-off batches.  Biztalk is more real-time integration.

Comment: Do does that mean in SSIS we cannot create orchestration or workflows?

Comment: Technically BizTalk could process data at scheduled intervals also, there is a schedule adapter but this can also be achieved in other ways.  I don't know if SSIS is going to have the business rules and orchestration/workflow functionality that BizTalk does.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Biztalk, but I do work with SSIS somewhat regularly.

> 2.Does SSIS have VS 2010 project template like we have for Biztalk Server?

Yep. In the SQL Server installer, install Business Intelligence Development Studio and Integration Services. That will add SSIS templates to Visual Studio.

> 3.For SSIS development which IDE should be used, can we use VS 2010 or need to work in SQL Server Management Studio?

Visual Studio or BIDS. BIDS is actually just a Visual Studio shell for SSIS, SSRS, and SSAS development. You can do server configuration and interact with the packages you've built from within SSMS, but you do your development in VS or BIDS.

Comment: As of SQL Server 2008 R2, SSIS project types are not supported in VS 2010, only VS 2008.